# Powermock not returning correct object static method

Tags: java, easymock, powermock

I am using PowerMock to try and mock a final class with static methods, but whenever my code calls `MyClass.getInstance()` it returns `null`

In my tests I have annotated the test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
```

In my method to make the mock I do the following

```
suppressConstructor(MyClass.class);
PowerMock.mockStatic(MyClass.class);
mockClass = PowerMock.createMock(MyClass.class);
expect(MyClass.getInstance()).andReturn(mockClass);
```

Should `PowerMock.createMock` create an `EasyMock` class?

When I call this in my code (`MyClass.getInstance()`), it always returns `null` but if I step through the test class the variable `mockClass` gets instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you using the EasyMock way of mocking. Have you replayed the MyClass before calling the `getInstance()` method, e.g.

```
PowerMock.replay(MyClass.class);
```

?

From the PowerMock [MockStatic](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) documentation:

> Use PowerMock.mockStatic(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) to mock all methods of this class.
>    Use PowerMock.replay(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) to change the class to replay mode.
>   Use PowerMock.verify(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) to change the class to verify mode.

Comment: This was indeed the problem I was replaying `mockClass` instead of `MyClass.class`